# SCP/RSYNC don't work in Crontab but work when run standalone

Tags: cron, rsync, scp

I need to copy a backup file to a backup server everyday. I am using PublicKey SSH authentication.

All of the things work **but not together**:

If I run this line in crontab

```
rsync /home/ubuntu/*date_backup.archive* ssh centos@10.x.x.x/home/centos/backup
```

This works and sends the backup correctly

But since the *date* in the filename of the .archive changes, I need to run a script. Then I create rsync_backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

date= ...

rsync /home/ubuntu/*date_backup.archive* ssh centos@10.x.x.x/home/centos/backup
```

Then, if I run this via terminal with bash rsync_backup.sh, it works and sends the backup correctly

BUT if I put

```
* * * * * bash /home/ubuntu/rsync_backup.sh
```

or

```
* * * * * bash /home/ubuntu/rsync_backup.sh
```

The backup doesn't reach the destination host.

Also, if I put in the script another test line on local (mkdir /home/centos/test) and launch with crontab, it works!

I tried also with SCP, still the same results!

Do you have some ideas? Source machine is Ubuntu and Destination is Centos

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try redirecting cron output to a logfile to capture error output?

Comment: Are you sure your command works outside of crontab? it looks malformed to me - in particular, the remote destination needs a `:` in it (otherwise it will be interpreted as local) and if `ssh` is meant to specify the remote shell it needs to be `-e ssh`. Regardless, like the preceding comment said, add some logging (both stdout and stderr) ex.  `* * * * * bash /home/ubuntu/rsync_backup.sh >/home/ubuntu/rsync_backup.log 2>&1` which should tell you why it's failing (my guess is failed ssh authentication).